# oracle sql query Error(32,61): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "FROM" when expecting one of the following: . ( ) , * @ % & = - + < / >

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_CHECKUSER (
P_USERNAME VARCHAR,
P_PASSWORD VARCHAR)
AS
v_USERDATA NVARCHAR:= '';BEGIN
V_USERDATA :=TO_CHAR(U.ID)||'_'||U.USERNAME ||'_' || TO_CHAR(DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('MANIPAL',U.PASSWORD)) || '_' || UPPER(R.ROLENAME)||'_'||
(CASE WHEN(CONVERT(DATE,SYSTIMESTAMP)>CONVERT(DATE,ISNULL FROM DUAL);
(EXPIRYDATE,INTERVAL '-1' DAY(5) +SYSTIMESTAMP)))'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END;/)
FROM USERMASTER U LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLEMASTER R ON U.ROLEID = R.ID WHERE U.MID = @USERNAME AND TO_CHAR (DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE('MANIPAL',U.PASSWORD)) =@PASSWORD AND U.ISACTIVE = 1
IF(LENGTH(RTRIM(@USERDATA)) = 0)THEN
SELECT 'FALSE' AS RESULT FROM DUAL;
ELSE
SELECT @USERDATA AS RESULT FROM DUAL;
END IF;
END
```

Comment: Hint: Search for `FROM`. Does any of them appear in an odd place?

Comment: check the number of brackets used, they are not matching
line 8 last bracket

Comment: not solved Sas.

Comment: Is this really the way you format your production code?

Comment: You said that this is Oracle, tagged it so, but - to me, your code just doesn't look like Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're confused about the convert function/how to use is null/how to select into something.

I tried to rewrite the code in order for it to make sense. Add the ampersands back where they belong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP_CHECKUSER (P_USERNAME    VARCHAR,
                                          P_PASSWORD    VARCHAR)
AS
   v_USERDATA    NVARCHAR := '';
   v_date_bool   VARCHAR2 (10);
   result        VARCHAR2 (10);
BEGIN

   V_USERDATA :=
         TO_CHAR (U.ID)
      || '_'
      || U.USERNAME
      || '_'
      || TO_CHAR (DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('MANIPAL', U.PASSWORD))
      || '_'
      || UPPER (R.ROLENAME)
      || '_'
      || v_date_bool
      ||SELECT CASE WHEN SYSTIMESTAMP > EXPIRYDATE THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE'     END
     FROM USERMASTER U LEFT OUTER JOIN ROLEMASTER R ON U.ROLEID = R.ID
    WHERE     U.MID = 'USERNAME'
          AND TO_CHAR (DECRYPTBYPASSPHRASE ('MANIPAL', U.PASSWORD)) =
                 'PASSWORD'
          AND U.ISACTIVE = 1;

   IF (LENGTH (RTRIM (V_USERDATA)) = 0)
   THEN
      RESULT := FALSE;
   ELSE
      RESULT := 'userData';
   END IF;
END;
```